# What do you call someone who subtly implies they are better than you?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is a good word for someone that is usually nice and cordiar, but randomly likes to imply they are "better than you?"  The implication is usually subtle, but it's done via a social snub, body language, a comment, or a 'friendy joke?"  The implication usually goes something like this: "yea, I'd watch that show, but" [because I'm an aristrocat, it's below me].

The implication is always ever so subtle that it's tough to comment on or make a fuss about.  Also, the implication is so light that it's hard to communicate what happened to someone that isn't there without full context (even the people there don't always pick up on it).

Comment: They are a 'snob'.

Comment: Sounds like a "[(verbal) eye-roller](http://treato.com/Efficacy,Eye+Rolling/?a=s)" (and therefore a 'slapper') to me.

Comment: For fun, check out Scott Adam's *Topper*: http://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=Topper

Answer (score 10):

**[Condescending](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/condescending?s=t)**

> **adjective**
>
> showing or implying a usually patronizing descent from dignity or superiority.
>
> **E.g.** *They resented the older neighbors' **condescending** cordiality.*

Answer (score 6):

**supercilious** (*adj.*):

behaving or looking as though one thinks one is superior to others

> *'His supercilious smile conveyed that he was not going to take anything we said seriously.'*

Etymology: from Latin '*superciliosus*' (haughty); '*supercilium*' (eyebrow, arrogance)

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/supercilious); [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/supercilious)

Answer (score 0):

*Humblebrag*- an ostensibly modest or self-deprecating statement said with the intention to draw attention to something one wants to show off.

See this sentence :-

"Uggggh just ate about fifteen piece of chocolate! Gotta learn to control myself when flying in the first class or they'll cancel my modelling contract LOL".

Answer (score -2):

To some extent, a **bragger**. When someone does something that is cool, then will brag about it for ages.